# How can I choose from files in local storage instead of from a hardcoded file in res/raw?

Tags: android, html, xml, file, xslt

I'm trying to write an app that will take an XML file and convert it to HTML using XSLT.

The structure of the XML files will always be the same, but the data inside will change.

I have managed to get it to work using an XML file hardcoded in res/raw.

How can I change the app so that I can choose an XML file from the local storage on the device?

Here is my code:

I have a MainActivity with just a single button that kicks off the Activity that is doing the conversion:

**MainActivity**

```html
package com.example.xml_html_webview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoadXSLTinWebview.class));
            }
        });
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity that does the conversion:**

```html
package com.example.xml_html_webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintJob;
import android.print.PrintManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.example.xml_html_webview.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class LoadXSLTinWebview extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);

        //Reading XSLT
        String strXSLT = GetStyleSheet(R.raw.xsltfile);
        //Reading XML
        String strXML = GetStyleSheet(R.raw.xmlfile);
        /*
         * Loading XSLT...
         */
        //Transform ...
        String html=StaticTransform(strXSLT, strXML);

        // HTML button added to transformed XML
        String html_button=
                "<html><script type=\"text/javascript\">function createWebPrintJob() {\nAndroid.createWebPrintJob();\n}</script><body><input type=\"button\" value=\"Print\" onClick=\"createWebPrintJob()\" />\n</body></html>";

        //Loading the above transformed CSLT in to Webview...
        webview.loadData(html + html_button,"text/html",null);


    }

    /*
     * Transform XSLT to HTML string
     */
    public static String StaticTransform(String strXsl, String strXml) {
        String html = "";

        try {

            InputStream ds = null;
            ds = new ByteArrayInputStream(strXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(ds);

            InputStream xs = new ByteArrayInputStream(strXsl.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xs);

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            Result result = new StreamResult(writer);
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
            transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);

            html = writer.toString();

            ds.close();
            xs.close();

            xmlSource = null;
            xsltSource = null;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return html;
    }

    /*
     * Read file from res/raw...
     */
    private String GetStyleSheet(int fileId) {
        String strXsl = null;

        InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(fileId);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int size = 0;
        // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while ((size = raw.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            raw.close();

            strXsl = outputStream.toString();

            Log.v("Log", "xsl ==> " + strXsl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return strXsl;

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem loading a txt or xml or xsl file from 'disk' and putting the contents in a string?

Comment: And who should choose a file? The user?

Comment: @blackapps - no problem with doing that, I just don't know how haha. 

Yes, the user needs to choose the correct xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to find a solution using FileUtils to convert my file to a string:

```html
File InstanceXmlFile = Collect.getInstance().getFormController().getInstanceFile();

        String strXML = null;
        try {
            strXML = FileUtils.readFileToString(InstanceXmlFile, "utf-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```